# Rails 3: Image streaming error: “The image … cannot be displayed because it contains errors”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-3, dreamhost

The log says:

```
Started GET "/assets/2/thumb" for 110.174.88.80 at Fri Jul 01 20:11:35 -0700 2011
  Processing by AssetsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2", "style"=>"thumb"}
[/home/misha_moroshko/myfamily.moroshko.com/public/images/thumb.jpg] found!
Sent file /home/misha_moroshko/myfamily.moroshko.com/public/images/thumb.jpg (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms
```

If you go directly to the image, it is fetched properly.

Note that this is a simplified example of my real problem. In the real case the image is not in the `public` folder, but the error is the same.

What could cause such an error ?

---

```
rails -v
=> Rails 3.0.1
ruby -v
=> ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]
```

---

Relevant code:

```
# config/routes.rb
match "assets/:id/:style" => "assets#show"

class AssetsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    path = Rails.root.join("public", "images", "thumb.jpg").to_s
    if File.exist?(path)
      logger.fatal "[#{path}] found!"
      send_file(path, { :type => "image/jpeg", :disposition => "inline" })
    else
      logger.fatal "[#{path}] not found!"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replacing

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
```

with

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Accel-Redirect"
```

in `config/environments/production.rb` solved the problem!

Comment: Wow, we should not have to do this...but I'm glad it's at least a little documented.

Answer (score 0):

The URL http://www.myfamily.moroshko.com/assets/2/thumb is sending the correct headers, but is not sending a body in the response.  Have you removed the code that @amb suggested you add?  It seems like it's going into your `else` block and just logging an error to your console.

Comment: Please check it now. I see: `[/home/misha_moroshko/myfamily.moroshko.com/public/images/thumb.jpg] found!`

Comment: Still not getting a response body.  You can try it with `curl -i http://www.myfamily.moroshko.com/assets/2/thumb` on the command line (on a Mac/Linux).

Comment: Well, probably this is the problem. The question is why?? It's not going to the `else` part, that's for sure... Any ideas what could cause the body to disappear ?

Comment: What is output to the console if you log `File.size?(path)` ?  Is the server seeing it as 0 bytes, perhaps?  A permissions error?  Just thinking out loud.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect there's a configuration problem between your Rails app and Passenger, but I don't really know much about that, sorry.  According the send_file documentation, it uses an HTTP header X-Sendfile, which is interpreted by the server, but something is amiss here.

Comment: @MishaMoroshko let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1076/discussion-between-d11wtq-and-misha-moroshko)

Comment: Haha, sorry, I didn't know it would just go ahead and create a chat when I clicked that link!

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I found a solution :) (See my answer)